# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined at Component.clickHandler

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular8

> I'm Currently working on Angular 8. What I'm trying to do here is
> change the color of div when it's selected. But when I click on div it
> gives me above mentioned error. Any Help would be very much
> appreciated

**My HTML Code**

```
  <div class="icon text-custom-white bg-light-green" id="myDIV" (click)="clickHandler(this)">

                  <img
                  src="{{category?.CategoryImage || 'https://giftclubimagestorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/biryani.jpg'}}"
                  class="rounded-circle"
                  alt="{{category?.CategoryTitle || ''}}" class="imgrr">

            </div>
```

**My CSS Code**

```
.icon {

}

.selected {

  border-color: 20px solid blue;

}
```

**My TS Code**

```
  clickHandler(element) {
    // Get currently selected element(s)
    const old = document.getElementsByClassName('icon');

    
    for (let i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
      // Remove current selected class
      console.log(old[i].classList.remove('selected'));
      }
    // On element that called the function add selected class
    element.classList.add('selected');
  }
```

Comment: `console.log(element)`

Comment: in your html this refers to the class in the typescript file not to the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `this` in your `(click)="clickHandler(this)"` doesn't refer to the element. It will refer to the `class Properties`.
Error is because that `element` on `element.classList.add('selected');` is `undefined`.

If you want to get the element on your `Component.ts` it's better to use `@viewChild`

But for your purpose here it's better to use `ngClass` and a simple `boolean` varibale like this example:

Sample code for you on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-e6x1yf?):

**Component.style.css**

```css
.selected {
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-color: 20px solid blue;
}
.not-selected {
  border-color: none;
}
```

**Component.template.html**

```html
<div (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]=" (isSelected) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected' ">Select Test</div>
```

**Component.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
}) 

export class AppComponent  {

  public isSelected: boolean = false;

  toggle = () => {
    this.isSelected = !this.isSelected
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, but it applies styling on all the images inside div. But I particularly want to do is to apply styling only on the selected image. And keep other images aside.

Comment: Got it. If you have more than one and for example use `*ngFor` to render them use a second property such as `imgID` and in `toggle` function get the `ID` too and in 'ngClass' add a second condition that if `imgID == ID` .

Comment: You mean something like this :                                                                                                         <div class="icon text-custom-white bg-light-green" id="myDIV" (click)="toggle()" [ngClass]="(isSelected) ? 'selected' : 'not-selected'" *ngIf="category?.CategoryImage">


                    </div>

Comment: No. I made a sample for you here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bqchrq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Oh, Thank You so much, man. You did an amazing job. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this before but I don't know if it's what exactly you want.
In my ts code,

```
selectedIndex:number;
```

In my html

```
<div class="icon text-custom-white bg-light-green {{selectedIndex = rowIndex? 'selected' : ''}}" id="myDIV" (click)="selectedIndex=rowIndex">

                  <img
                  src="{{category?.CategoryImage || 'https://giftclubimagestorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/biryani.jpg'}}"
                  class="rounded-circle"
                  alt="{{category?.CategoryTitle || ''}}" class="imgrr">

            </div>
```

Assuming you are looping the category from an array using ng-for-index